# Post API authorization

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I'm beginner in python but I would like to get info data from my private account on cryptocurrency market bitbay.net.

[Api description can be found here:](https://bitbay.net/pl/api-prywatne)

My code in Python 3.5:

```
import requests
import json
import hashlib
import time

hash_object = hashlib.sha512(b'public_api_xxxxxx')
apihash = hash_object.hexdigest()    
timestamp = time.time()

p = requests.post('https://bitbay.net/API/Trading/tradingApi.php', data={'API-Key':'public_api_xxxxxx','API-Hash':apihash,'Moment':timestamp, 'Method':'info' })
p.text
print(p)
```

I spend many hours to fix that but I still get:

Response [404]

Your assistance will be very much appreciated. For best answer I would like buy small beer :) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform [`hash_mac`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) equivalent, you can use [`hmac`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html) :

```
apihash = hmac.new(secret, data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
```

Also, from the doc, `API-Key` and `API-Hash` are headers. `moment` & `method` field are url encoded in the body

Python2

```
import requests
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
import urllib

secret = "12345"
apiKey = "public_api_xxxxxx"

timestamp = int(time.time())

data = urllib.urlencode((('method', 'info'),('moment', timestamp)))

apihash = hmac.new(secret, data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

res = requests.post('https://bitbay.net/API/Trading/tradingApi.php',
    headers={
    'API-Key':apiKey,
    'API-Hash' : apihash,
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data=data
)

print(res)
print(res.text)
```

Python3

```
import requests
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
import urllib

secret = b"12345"
apiKey = "public_api_xxxxxx"

timestamp = int(time.time())

data = urllib.parse.urlencode((('method', 'info'),('moment', timestamp)))

apihash = hmac.new(secret, data.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

res = requests.post('https://bitbay.net/API/Trading/tradingApi.php',
    headers={
    'API-Key':apiKey,
    'API-Hash' : apihash,
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data=data
)

print(res)
print(res.text)
```

Comment: Thank You for help! You are the Boss :) Send me please your cryptocurrency wallet adress - I would like to buy You a beer :)

Comment: You're welcome I'm glad I could help, you can accept / upvote the answer if you like it, that would be fine :)

Comment: Ok. Thank You :)